# Add scipy sparse row matrix to another sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

I have a `csr_matrix` `A` of shape `(70000, 80000)` and another `csr_matrix` `B`of shape `(1, 80000)`. How can I efficiently add B to every row of A? One idea is to somehow create a sparse matrix `B'` which is rows of `B` repeated, but `numpy.repeat` does not work and using a matrix of ones to create `B'` is very memory inefficient.

I also tried iterating through every row of `A` and adding `B` to it, but that again is very time inefficient.

**Update:**
I tried something very simple which seems to be very efficient than the ideas I mentioned above. The idea is to use `scipy.sparse.vstack`:

```
C = sparse.vstack([B for x in range(A.shape[0])])
A + C
```

This performs well for my task! Few more realizations: I initially tried an iterative approach where I called `vstack`multiple times, this approach is slower than calling it just once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`A + B[np.zeros(A.shape[0])]` is another way to expand `B` to the same shape as `A`.

It has about the same performance and memory footprint as [Warren Weckesser's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34583780/190597):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sparse

N, M = 70000, 80000
A = sparse.rand(N, M, density=0.001).tocsr()
B = sparse.rand(1, M, density=0.001).tocsr()
```

---

```
In [185]: %timeit u = sparse.csr_matrix(np.ones((A.shape[0], 1), dtype=B.dtype)); Bp = u * B; A + Bp
1 loops, best of 3: 284 ms per loop

In [186]: %timeit A + B[np.zeros(A.shape[0])]
1 loops, best of 3: 280 ms per loop
```

and appears to be faster than using  `sparse.vstack`:

```
In [187]: %timeit A + sparse.vstack([B for x in range(A.shape[0])])
1 loops, best of 3: 606 ms per loop
```

Comment: This is cleaner than mine; +1.

Comment: In fact, this moots my answer.  Poof!  It's gone.

Comment: @unubtu, what kind of shell/interpreter are you using? The thing that prints "In [185]"?

Comment: I found (after too much playing) that `sparse.bsr_matrix((np.tile(B.data(N,1)).T[:,:,None], B.indices, B.indptr), shape=(N,M))` creates the correct matrix in `bsr` format, and does so quite fast.  But applying `tocsr` so it can be added puts the net time into same range as your answers.